# hadoop streaming with c# on linux/osx machines

Tags: c#, linux, macos, hadoop

I thought I would try hadoop streaming out with c# binaries as the -mapper and -reducer. Unfortunately, it seems that the streaming jar can't take c# .exes. What method is there to get hadoop to play nice with c# code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far the best solution (although I would fain call it that), is to make a shell script that called the c# executable, and pass that into hadoop's streaming jar.

Answer (score 0):

Basically the problem is that .exe files are not executable on linux... you can experiment with wine however, I am not sure if standard input and standard output streaming will work fine, and that is what the streaming uses.

When you use streaming (in a heavily simplified way) the following happens:

```
cat inputfile > mapper > reducer > output
```

and here mapper and reducer are programs that has to be runnable by the operating system.

So install wine, and try `-mapper "wine your_program.exe"` instead of `-mapper your_program.exe`.
The problem will be that wine should be installed on all your worker nodes, and also you may need to fix a problems related to wine usage...

I would encourage you to experiment with hadoop streaming with a simpler thing first... for example a shell script or python or something that runs out of the box on your worker nodes.

Comment: I've gotten python to work rather easily. I figured out that I could shove "mono myc#.exe" into a .sh script though.